# Which approach is mostly used to create an electronic device?

Tags: design, cpu, firmware

I am very new to electronics, what I know so far (which may be wrong) is that there are two approaches to create an electronic device (examples of electronic device: pocket calculator, TV remote control, etc.):

- The electronic device would have a CPU that execute a firmware
- Or the electronic device would have its logic/algorithm "implemented in hardware" (so a CPU and a firmware do not exist)

Which of these two approaches is mostly used to create an electronic device?

Comment: There's no most or least. But more complicated algorithms are definitely done in firmware. But there's also FPGAs which are configurable hardware where you don't run code but tell how the logic gates inside the FPGA need to connect together. It's like building on a board with a bunch of logic gate ICs, except you don't have to physically build it; You can type it into a file. It's not running instructions like firmware.

Comment: This is too broad, and depends a lot on what you consider "a device". Also, not everything has logic or an algorithm "implemented in hardware". An audio amplifier doesn't execute code or evaluate logic that says that it should amplify -- it directly takes an input voltage, and amplifies it through an arrangement of transistors.

Comment: @Steven what about an LED taped to a coin cell? ... what algorithm is implemented there?

Comment: Mostly both, sometimes at the same time :)

Comment: If cost is very tight and production volume is very high, people will do almost anything to reduce the BOM cost, including design custom chips. But for low volume or high complexity, it is more likely that they will use an off-the-shelf chip with custom FW.

Comment: If a device has a non-trivial logical or algorithmic function, then it will have a CPU, or something that's equivalent to one (custom controller, or uC implemented in FPGA). Only the most trivial of operations would be done without - if 'on' switch pressed AND 'battery voltage OK' THEN 'switch on' sort of thing.

Comment: *Always* a microcontroller, unless it's unsuitable for some reason such as being too slow! If you want a pocket calculator, a remote control, or a toy, then it's *not* too slow and you should definitely use one. But if you want to run a neural network, then you will be looking at more "serious" CPUs at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

This question is too broad but I'm happy to give a few pointers.

In our days, most electronic devices contains some sort of CPU, MCU or FPGA, because the cost have become so low that it doesn't make much sense anymore to implement logic in hardware.

In some cases, like remote control, toys, specialized dirt-cheap chips may be used that implements the logic in place of an MCU, but this is only for high volume products and the entry price to design such chip is high.

Another example is the NE555 timer chip that was widely used, and still fairly, but if you intend to have a circuit doing more than blinking an LED, it makes much more sense to have an MCU with the timer programmed in it.

Some specific fields, like high-end audio, may have some products that are still purely analog.

If you are new to electronic, you want to use MCUs for the logic, this is what will get you started and give you the most freedom in doing designs.